# Error on clicking a button in IE using Excel macros

Tags: vba, excel

I am able to successfully launch IE using Vb in macros. i tried acessing google and when i tried sigining in to google, it throws an error in my code stating "`Object Variable or with block variable not set`" . 
Please find the code below

```
Sub abce()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument


Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Navigate "http://www.google.com"
ie.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

  Set doc = ie.Document


  doc.getElementsByClassName("gb_T gb_R").Item.Click (Note - Click sign in button on google page)
  **doc.getElementsByName("signIn").Item.Click** (Note - click sign in button on login page)


End Sub
```

In the above code am able to click "`Sign in button`" in google page. when i comes to login page it throws an error in the code `doc.getElementsByName("signIn").Item.Click` stating `Object Variable or with block variable not set` 

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.  Replace

doc.getElementsByName("signIn").Item.Click   ' ** (Note - click sign in button on login page

with

doc.getElementbyID("signIn").Click   ' (Note - click sign in button on login page)

Comment: Thanks :) it worked. One more question here. Is there a way to navigate through webtables in a webpage using macros?

Comment: Usually yes, post another question with specifics